# Firefox only glitch with link hover and use of onmouseover / onmouseout

Tags: firefox, hover, onmouseover, onmouseout, blink

Hi guys I'm getting some strange behavior using Firefox with  in combination with onMouseOver and onMouseOut - Events.

I got this code i.e:

```
    <a href='examplelink' onmouseover='showPopup();' onmouseout='hidePopup();'>My example link</a>
```

This shows a popup onmouseover and hides it onmouseout. Fine in every other browser, except for Firefox. 
The problem is, when I hover the link on the top of the link, everything seems to work. But when I hover the link on the lower third, the cursor changes all the time from mouse pointer to default cursor and the popup opens and hides and opens and hides and ...

Anyone here has this problem too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your `showPopup` shows the popup under the pointer, so that of course triggers a mouseout on the link, which hides the popup, so now the pointer is over the link again, triggering a mouseover, etc.

Comment: So, well, that seemed to be the problem here. Thanks! However it is strange, that this issue only appears in firefox..

Comment: Other UAs don't consistently update hover state on layout changes.